# Proof that this map is well-defined $ \phi(a \bmod{mn})= (a \bmod m, a \bmod n) $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

As part of a proof of the Chinese-remainder equivalent of groups, I want to show that:

> $$ \phi(a \bmod mn)= (a \bmod m, a \bmod n) $$
>   is a well-defined map

Note that $\gcd(m,n)=1$ so they are coprime.

We usually need to show that given: $a \equiv b \mod {mn}$, we are able to demonstrate that: $$ \phi(a)=\phi(b)$$

So let's start out writing what both this means.
$$ (a \bmod m, a \bmod n)=(b \bmod m, b \bmod n)$$
We get the systems of equations:
$$ a \bmod m = b \bmod m$$
$$ a \bmod n = b\bmod n$$

Why is this result true, if it is true I can work my way from bottom to top and arrive at the desired result.

Comment: $mn\mid a-b\,\Rightarrow\, m,n\mid a-b,\,$ i.e. congruences *persist* mod divisors of the modulus.

Comment: This answers my question, very simple, but very nice. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great. Strangely such persistence is often not highlighted early on in elementary number theory courses so many folks first stumble upon it in more complex context such as CRT - making it harder to comprehend. But we know it implicitly long before that, e.g. coputing the parity of an integer from the parity of its decimal units digit. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3012964/242) for further examples and discussion.